# Got "401 from http://localhost:8001/admin/v1/instance-admin" error when running MarkLogic docker image

Tags: docker-compose, sparql, marklogic

I am following this example:

```
$ docker run -d -it -p 8000:8000 -p 8001:8001 -p 8002:8002
     -e MARKLOGIC_INIT=true
     -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME='admin'
     -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD='Areally!PowerfulPassword1337'
     marklogicdb/marklogic-db
```

but got this response:

> Info: Installing admin username and password, and initialize the security database and objects.
> Expected response code 202, got 401 from `http://localhost:8001/admin/v1/instance-admin`.

I tried `sudo` but did not work. Any help?

I am waiting to launch MarkLogic server and use a SPARQL endpoint.

Full log:

> Info: Starting MarkLogic container with 11.0.2-centos-1.0.2 from release/docker-1.0.2
>
> Info: OVERWRITE_ML_CONF is false, not writing to /etc/marklogic.conf
>
> Info: INSTALL_CONVERTERS is false, not installing converters.
>
> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
>
> Starting MarkLogic:                    [  OK  ]
>
> Info: MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD is set, using ENV for admin password.
>
> Info: MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME is set, using ENV for admin username.
>
> Info: MARKLOGIC_WALLET_PASSWORD is set, using ENV for wallet-password.
>
> Info: MARKLOGIC_INIT is true, initializing the MarkLogic server.
>
> Info: Initializing MarkLogic on 7ff8c28250e4
>
> Info: Waiting for MarkLogic to restart.
>
> Info: MarkLogic has restarted.
>
> Info: Installing admin username and password, and initialize the security database and objects.
>
> Error: Expected response code 202, got 401 from `http://7ff8c28250e4:8001/admin/v1/instance-admin`.

**UPDATE**
It seems to be an issue with Apple M1. Apparently, rosetta2 is required to be set to run MarkLogic on M1.

Comment: I just tried this, though I tossed it all on one line to make sure I didn't run into any whitespace/newline issues in my terminal - docker run -d -it -p 8000:8000 -p 8001:8001 -p 8002:8002 -e MARKLOGIC_INIT=true -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME='admin' -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD='Areally!PowerfulPassword1337' marklogicdb/marklogic-db . That successfully created a new container that I was able to access via localhost:8001 . Maybe try running the command on one line?

Comment: If you still have issues, please include the full output of the log. It should start with a line like "Info: Starting MarkLogic container".

Comment: Hi all ! I updated the post with the full log. Thanks!
BTW, I could create the container and access via 8001 but after a few seconds I got this error and the container stops